# Why can't I edit a List member directly in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a class declared as `public class DatumSet : List<datum>`, where

```
public struct datum {
    public UInt32[] chan;
    public UInt64 sample_number;
    public float time;
    public UInt32 source_sector;
}
```

I want to iterate through the List and make some changes.  Why does this NOT work

```
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++) {
            this[i].sample_number = startSample;
            this[i].time = (float)startSample / _sample_rate;
            startSample++;
        }
```

but this DOES work

```
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++) {
            datum d = this[i];
            d.sample_number = sampleNumber;
            d.time = (float)sampleNumber / _sample_rate;
            sampleNumber++;
        }
```

I get the error:

Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List.this[int]' because it is not a variable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're having problems because you are using a struct rather than a class.

When you retrieve a struct from a collection, a copy is made. Your first set of code gives you an error because it detects you're doing something you may not mean to do. You'd actually be editing a copy of the struct rather than the copy in the collection.

The second doesn't produce an error because you explicitly pull the copy out of the collection before editing. This code may compile, but won't modify any of the structs in the collection and thus won't give you the results that you're expecting.

Answer (score 13):

This is what you get for using a mutable value type :)

Think of an indexer as just like a method call. So this:

```
this[i].sample_number = startSample;
```

is like:

```
GetValue(i).sample_number = startSample;
```

But because `datum` is a value type (a struct), the method is returning a *copy* of the value in the list - so modifying it would do you no good at all.

The compiler is stopping you from making that mistake.

You *claim* that this works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++) {
    datum d = this[i];
    d.sample_number = sampleNumber;
    d.time = (float)sampleNumber / _sample_rate;
    sampleNumber++;
}
```

... but in reality, it does nothing useful. It's equivalent to:

```
sampleNumber += this.Count;
```

That's all. It *compiles*, but that's not the same as it *working*.

I would suggest that you make all value types immutable; it helps to prevent you from getting into this mess. So *either* you can keep `datum` as a value type, and replace the value in the list on each iteration, *or* you can change it to be a class, and modify the objects via the *reference* stored in the list.

(Either way, I'd strongly suggest that you start using properties instead of public fields, and start following .NET naming conventions too.)

Comment: I was just about to comment, "where is Jon Skeet when you need him?"

Comment: Hmm, this is new to me.  Structs are mutable and classes are immutable?  If I just changed the keyword 'struct' to 'class' would that be sufficient or do i have to add get/set methods too?

Comment: @reza: No, structs and classes can both be mutable or immutable - it's up to you. But you *really* need to understand the differences between structs and classes. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html

Comment: @jonskeet I looked over the document but it didn't help much. Just looks like one uses a class and the other a struct.  How do you make a struct immutable?  How do I get a reference to an object in the list without making a copy of it?

Comment: btw, i do a lot of C coding, so am familiar with pointers/etc, not not some of the details of C#

Comment: @reza: The first thing to do is *not* treat C# like C :) They're completely different languages, and you should treat them differently. Ignore the fact that they both use braces and semi-colons, and learn C# from scratch, ideally from a good book. Don't just "look over" a document, tutorial or book - read them *thoroughly*, assuming that every sentence may contain something you didn't know before.

Comment: Will I get the behavior I want from making the struct to a class or do I need to do additional work?  according to your example, making it a class is all I need to do.

Comment: @reza: Yes, that will fix it - but you *should* do more. You *should* fix your naming conventions, and you *should* avoid public fields which are the enemy of encapsulation... and you definitely *should* make sure you understand exactly why it will fix it, and why the compiler was complaining. Oh, and understand why the code you thought worked really wasn't working.

Comment: @reza: Classes can be mutable or immutable.  Structs which allow for easy mutation have semantics very different from any kind of class, while structs which are only awkwardly mutable offer semantics which are close to those of immutable classes.  To edit part of a conveniently-mutable struct which is stored in a `List<T>`, one must read the struct from the list, modify it, and then *write it back*.  Not until the write-back operation will the copy of the struct stored in the list be affected.  Such an approach is less convenient than editing part of a struct stored in an array...

Comment: @reza: ...but will nonetheless in many cases still yield code which is cleaner, clearer, more maintainable, and more efficient than would be possible using any other kind of type.  Note that if `myList` is a `List<T>`, and `T` is a mutable class type with read-write property `X`, it's easy to update the value of `MyList[1].X` (simply say e.g. `MyList[1].X += 4;`), but it may be hard to know whether that will affect the value of `MyList[0].X` or `SomeOtherList[5].X`.  Conveniently-mutable structs avoid have that problem.