# Is it possible to access a reference of a struct from a List<T> to make changes?

Tags: c#, list, struct, immutability, mutable

I have a struct which I put in a `List<T>`, I want to edit some value in that struct at a specific position.  Is this at all possible without making a copy of the struct, editing the copy, and replacing the entry in the List?

Comment: That's the main difference of `struct` from `class`. So consider to use classes instead.

Comment: I've removed "immutable" from title as it did not make not much sense in sentence "immutable changes"... @reza please check if title reflects your question, rollback edit otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, to be able to do it you need reference to element of inner array which is not provided by `List`/`IList`.

You can do that with unsafe code and arrays if you have to.

Comment: +1: I missed that...could you, please, explain in greater detail, why is that so. What does the `List<T>` return by element index?

Comment: from my understanding, it is a copy of the contents.  it is treated like an integer. not sure why that is advantageous or why it works that way.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov, yes what reza said. `struct` in C# are  value types and always copy whole content - see Jon's http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html article about struct vs class.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov why then the code I posted in my answer does the trick?

Comment: @reza, note that C++ behave very similar way (bitwise copy by default), the difference is that you usually have versions of most methods with "by reference" arguments/results.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the issue is not in `i`, but a little higher...I've shortned my answer, please, see it...The value in the array has changed, or not?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov, (removed wrong comment - Array is not List and array allows changes)... I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

As of now there are `CollectionsMarshal` class with function AsSpan to get internal span of List https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal

With span, we can get a reference of item in the List and modified it directly like an array

Answer (score 1):

From J.Richter's "CLR via C#", 3rd edition:

> Value types should be immutable: that is, they should not define any
>   members that modify any of the type’s instance fields. In fact, I
>   recommended that value types have their fields marked as readonly so
>   that the compiler will issue errors should you accidentally write a
>   method that attempts to modify a field.

...

> Just keep in mind that value types and reference types have very
>   different behaviors depending on how they’re used.

---

Consider this code:

```
public interface IChangeStruct
{
    int Value { get; }
    void Change(int value);
}

public struct MyStruct : IChangeStruct
{
    int value;

    public MyStruct(int _value)
    {
        value = _value;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public void Change(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and it's usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyStruct[] l = new MyStruct[]
        {
            new MyStruct(0)
        };
    Console.WriteLine(l[0].Value);
    l[0].Change(10);
    Console.WriteLine(l[0].Value);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output is:

> 0
>   10

So it does what you need.

However the same won't work for `List<T>`. I guess by the reason, mentioned by Alexei Levenkov. So, I would strongly recommend you to change `struct` to `class` if the type in question is not immutable per instance.

Comment: This is useful... but not directly answering the question... I think it was covered enough in reza's previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483338/why-cant-i-edit-a-list-member-directly-in-c-sharp

Comment: Structs which expose mutating interfaces have very quirky semantics.  It's far better to simply have structs expose their fields directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to have your structures expose their fields directly, and then use code like:

```
  var temp = myList[3];
  temp.X += 4;
  myList[3] = temp;
```

I consider the failure of .net to provide any means of updating list items in place to be a significant weakness in .net, but would still consider an exposed-field struct as being far superior to any alternative in cases where one wishes to represent a small group of orthogonal values which should not be "attached" to any other such group (such as the coordinates in a point, the origin and size of a rectangle, etc.)  The notion that structs should be "immutable" has been repeated as mantra for a long time, but that doesn't mean it's good advice.  Such notion stems largely from two things:

1. Structs which modify `this` in any members outside their constructors are quirky.  Such quirks used to (and to some extent still do) apply to property setters, but not to structs which simply expose their fields directly.  Because Microsoft wrapped all struct fields in properties, this meant that while mutable structures could have had sensible semantics if they'd had exposed fields, they ended up with quirky semantics; Microsoft then blamed the quirky semantics on the fact that structs were mutable, rather than on the needless wrapping of fields with properties.

   Some people like to model .net has only having one kind of object, as opposed to having value types and reference types as distinct kinds of entities.  The behavior of so-called "immutable" value types is close enough to that of reference types that they can pretend they're the same thing, whereas the behavior of easily-mutable value types is vastly different.  In reality, it's easier to understand the behavior of exposed-field value types than to understand all the corner cases where so-called "immutable" value types behave differently from reference types, and understanding the latter is impossible without understanding the former.  Note that while value types may pretend to be immutable, there is in reality no such thing as an immutable value type.  The only distinction is between those which can be mutated conveniently and those which can only be mutated awkwardly.

In reality, if a type is supposed to represent a small group of orthogonal values, an exposed-field struct is a perfect fit.  Even if one has to use clunky code like that shown above to update a field of an item in a `List<structType>`, it's better than any alternative using class types or so-called "immutable" structs.  Knowing that `myList` is a structure with an exposed field `X` would be enough to completely understand the code above.  The only remotely decent alternative if one were using a class or "immutable" struct would be `myList[3] = myList[3].WithX(myList[3].X + 4);`, but that would require that the type in question to offer a `WithX` method (and presumably a `WithWhatever()` method for each field).  Such methods would increase many fold the amount of code one would have to read to find out for certain what a method would actually do (one might *expect* that `WithX` would return a new instance which was identical to the old one except for the value of `X`, but one wouldn't know until one read all the code involved; by contrast, knowing that `X` is an exposed field of the structure type would be sufficient to *know* what the above code would do.

Comment: Supercat, thank you for being the first person to give me a practical answer rather than one that is based on mantra and tradition.  I just want my code to be fast, and could care less about all the setter and getters which make things look pretty. Additionally, I have a hard time imagining that it wouldn't be faster to reference a parameter from a struct array (or List<T>) than it is from a list of objects by reference.  Additionally, I see little distinction from a struct in C# than an object, as you have have methods inside structs, etc.

Comment: Why isn't there a simple STRUCT struct in C# that doesn't try to act like an object?  Why not just not have structs if they are almost-functionally equivalent and add some other language to denote that you want a copy of the object or a reference to the object?

Comment: I do have to learn some of the jargon [convenient/awkward] [mutable/immutable] [reference/object/value] type.  I'm assuming that immutable just means that you dont have a setter for a parameter outside the object. convenient/awkward I assume referes to how ugly the code looks to do something.  It would be nice if references had a prefix like * to make them easy to spot (like C).  

all in all, I like c#, i think it takes a lot of the good aspects of java, C, perl -- though I don't like how it (at least it seems to me) forces you to write potentially slower code.

Comment: I also don't like how the limit on the comment size on this website but no limitation on the number of comments...

Comment: @reza: In .NET (and thus in C#), a struct definition actually defines two kinds of things: (1) the type of a heap object, which derives from `System.ValueType` which in turn inherits from `Object`, and which like all heap objects stores a type descriptor along with the contents of all public and private fields; (2) the type of a storage location which holds all the struct's public and private fields, but doesn't store any type information.  Heap objects of structure types behave, from the perspective of outside code, like heap objects of class types.  The biggest difference...

Comment: ...between structure types and class types is that storage locations of class types hold a heap object reference, while storage locations of structure types hold the struct fields.  Unfortunately, some people seem to regard structures as being class objects that don't work quite right, rather than as an entity which isn't a heap object, but can be converted to or from a heap-object representation.   In Java, there are no non-primitive value types, an omission which is IMHO a major weakness.  Java doesn't explicitly indicate `Foo.Bar` refers not to a member of `Foo`, but one of its target...

Comment: ...because unless `Foo` is a value primitive (e.g. `int`) it can't possibly store anything other than a reference to an object, so `Foo.Bar` can't refer to anything within `Foo` itself.  Even though .NET has value types, it retains Java's elision of the dereferencing operator.  All value types may be mutated via assignment, which mutates all the fields of the destination to match those of the source.  Some can only be mutated by using a factory method or constructor to make a new instance which is then copied and abandoned, but that sequence still works by mutating the destination.